# On save_post need to wp_insert_post and save partent post id to child post and child post id to parent post

Tags: plugins, wp-insert-post, save-post

I'working on plugin for custom post types and it's metadata etc. Everything is fine so far but now I need to extend this plugin - I need to create one extra the same custom post on save/edit post when certain metadata has value X. And I'm stucked to figure out how to get 2 values:
1)Insert "Parent" post ID to "Child" post to specific metadata
2)Insert "Child" post ID to "Parent" post to specific metadata

Here is code:

```
add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_post_type_example_meta_boxes'));
function save_post_type_example_meta_boxes($post_id)
   ..........
  if (...) {
    $new_custom_post = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => '',
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
                'meta_input'   => array(
                    'meta_1' => 'X',
                    'parent_post_id' => ???
                  ),
    );
    wp_insert_post($new_custom_post );
  }
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'child_post_id', ???);
  ......
  if(isset($_POST['meta_x_post'])) {
        $meta_x = sanitize_text_field($_POST['meta_x_post']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_x', $meta_x);
    }
...
}
```

here it could be $post_id (because it's the ID for Parent post)?

Any suggestions how to get Child post ID?

Thank you!

Comment: When you insert a post, the ID of the new post is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_post_type_example_meta_boxes'));
function save_post_type_example_meta_boxes($post_id)
..........

    if (...) {
        $new_custom_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => '',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
            'meta_input'   => array(
                'meta_1' => 'X',
                'parent_post_id' => $post_id,
            ),
        );

        // Prevent this action from running twice.
        remove_action( 'save_post', [ $this, 'save_post_type_example_meta_boxes' ] );
        $child_post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_custom_post );
        // Readd the action.
        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_post_type_example_meta_boxes'));
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'child_post_id', $child_post_id);
    ......
    if(isset($_POST['meta_x_post'])) {
        $meta_x = sanitize_text_field($_POST['meta_x_post']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_x', $meta_x);
    }
...
}
```

And here's what I changed:

- The incoming post ID to `save_post_type_example_meta_boxes` should be what you want to use as your "parent" post ID.
- You should temporarily remove your hook to `save_post` so that it doesn't try to run on that action over and over again.
- As noted by @Milo, `wp_insert_post` returns a post ID on success, so that would give you the "child" post ID.

Comment: TNX! Working fine! Good tip about removing save_post filter and then enable back...yes, without that it created bulk of posts, was need to restart apache...